# The IAM authentication failed for the role postgres. Check the IAM token for this role and try again

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I'm facing a hard time connecting Python Lambdas to RDS proxy.

I have rest api that has a few Javascript and python lambdas and I manage and deploy everything using CDK.
I made sure that the lambdas can connect to the RDS proxy and handled all the roles and permissions.

In both Javascript and Python I generate an auth token to be used as a password for IAM authentication with the RDS proxy.

The problem is that Python Lambdas always throw this error:

> The IAM authentication failed for the role postgres. Check the IAM
> token for this role and try again.

while Javascript doesn't and connect to the proxy.

I'm using psycopg2 with sqlalchemy in Python and the following is how I create the db engine.

```
session = boto3.Session( 
aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            region_name=region,
        )

client = session.client('rds')

token = client.generate_db_auth_token(host, port, user_name, region)

_engine = create_engine('postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(
            user=user_name,
            host=host,
            port=port,
            db=db_name,
            password=token
        ), connect_args={'sslmode': 'require'},)
```

The role attached to the lambda:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds-db:connect",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:dbuser:prx-xxxxxxxxxx/postgres"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue. Assuming the lambda function can assume the role and all the other IAM policies are in place, here are a few things to check (in no particular order).

1 - **SQLModel vs SQLAlchemy**

I was able to use sqlalchemy to `create_engine(url)` where the token was used a the password in the url string. However, the same url did not work when using SQLModel `create_engine(url)`.I had to to:

```py
def get_connection():
   token = boto3.generate_db_token(DBHostname=host, DBUsername=dbuser, Region='us-east-1', Port=5432)
   return psycopg2.connect(host=host, port=5432, database=dbname, user=dbuser, password=token)
```

and then create the database engine with:

```py
url = f'postgresql://{dbuser}@{host}:5432/{dbname}?sslmode=require'
database = sqlmodel.create_engine(url, creator=get_connection)
```

This resolved my IAM credentials issue.

2 - **Secrets and KMS keys**

Ensure whatever role you've assigned to the proxy has access to the db users (e.g. "postgres" or "my_user_1") username and passwords stored as separate secrets in aws secrets manager. The secrets should be encrypted, so the same role has to be able to use the key to decrypt.

3 - **Dont use admin ("postgres") user**

From your rds-connect policy it looks like you are trying to log in as user "postgres", which is the default administrator username for new postgres instance. Even if that's what you want, I don't think that will work.

1. Create a new read-write role and another role with login on your actual RDS instance (not the proxy) [aws blog on postgres roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/)

```sql
CREATE ROLE my_user_1 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'my_secret_for_secretsmanager'
```

2. Modify your `rds-db:connect' policy to include that user

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
    [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds-db:connect",
            "Resource":
            [
                "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:dbuser:prx-xxxxxxxxxx/postgres",
                "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:dbuser:prx-xxxxxxxxxx/my_user_1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Use 'my_user_1' in your application code to generate the token and create the database engine

4 - **VPC issues**

The RDS instance and the RDS proxy have to be in the same VPC and use the same subnets. And the instance must use a security group (sg-instance) that accepts TCP traffic on port 5432 with a source security group used by proxy (sg-proxy). Then sg-proxy should allow all incoming traffic and have restricted outgoing traffic to TCP on port 5432.

Furthermore, your lambda has to have the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole (arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole)

Finally, your lambda has to be assigned to the same VPC as your instance and proxy.

**NOTE on debugging** You cannot connect to your proxy from the public internet. This is not obvious when you start using proxy, but it is the case [aws faq](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-proxy-connection-issues/). Just be sure you're code is running from inside the vpc. I think you can use the SAM CLI "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html" or log onto a free-tier ec2 with all the requisite dependencies.